# How to turn off bracket autocompletion in HTML in VSCode?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, in HTML mode, when I type in a square bracket (`[`) and then an alphabet (`[s`), the editor displays autocompletion for `<div s="|">|</div>`.

In other words, the bracket (`[`) followed by a character tries to autocomplete a `<div>` element with the given attribute.

I don't want to have this feature, since it slows down my typing as I am trying to write articles for some JavaScript internals that heavily use things like `[[Prototype]]`, `[[Writable]]` and so on.

Is there any way to turn this feature off in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

As per [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) you can use this setting:

```json
"emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "never"
```